# Access variable on one thread from another thread - Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Hi i have created and Activity. Lets assume BaseActivity. I have created a new thread in that activity.

Actually i have read and came to know that Threads are not garbage collected once the activity is destroyed on onConfigurationChange or some other and MEMORY IS LEAKED.

There are 2 rules to fix this.

One making the Thread class as Static one and the other is to stop the thread explicitly in onDestroy. I have done the both.

I have created this thread to Query a Content Provider. So I managed to get the applicationContext into the Thread and started using it. But unfortunately i cannot use the Cursor which I declared in OnCreate, like "Cursor myCursor;" . I tried assigning the returned cursor to this myCursor. It asks me to create a local variable. I think this is problem with the Activity Context.

I thought as I got the application Context, "I got the Whole application context". But unfortunately not. I even searched and found out that I should get a WeakReference to the outer Class. I clearly understood about WekaReference But unfortunately for my situation I dont know how to get weak reference of my outer class. kindle help me.

I even tried passing the activity Context to the thread constructor like MyThread(BaseActivity.this) and i dont know how to use this inside the thread.

```
public class MediaActivity extends Activity {
ExpandableListView expList ;
ExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter;
List<String> albumHead;
HashMap<String, List<String>> albumChild;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_media);

    ExpandableListView expList = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.mediaList);

    Cursor albumCursor;
    AlbumThread albumThread = new AlbumThread();
    albumThread.start();
}

private static class AlbumThread extends Thread{
    Context appContext = MediaApp.getAppContext();
    Context mediaActivity;

    public AlbumThread() {
        super("AlbumThread");

    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Query Media Contents from MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        super.run();
        ContentResolver albumResolver = appContext.getContentResolver();
        Uri mediaContentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] mediaColumns = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,


            };

        String mediaSort = "ORDER BY" + MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID + "ASC" + "," + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + "ASC"; 

        albumCursor = albumResolver.query(mediaContentUri, mediaColumns, null, null, mediaSort);

    }


}
```

}

Comment: post your code, please.

Comment: A public variable to an object/class is accessible from all other objects, regardless of thread.

Comment: @HowardPautz Above is my code. I am Beginner too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant access it because you declared it locally in your method.

Put your declaration of cursor, outside the onCreate()

you can put it:

```
     public Cursor myCursor;
```

This way you will be able to access it.

Comment: So for every view I need to update Should I need to declare them at the scope? also if i declare It asks me to create as a static variable. Is it ok?

Comment: Is there no other way to pass in the Context of the activity while creating thread, like MyThread(Myactivity.this)?

Comment: @RaajForu wondering if your approach is causing you the problem. Why do you need to pass context to the thread, to do a callback from the thread to the threads launcher ? Also, using Runnable is frequently easier than Thread. Also onCreate is may not be the best place to start a thread. If that cursor is going to be accessed in another thread, you may introduce hard-to-catch data contention / data ready bugs, e.g. is the cursor still fetching when the thread asks to use it, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I understood. Now I have setup Query in another thread. Also I am using the cursor to extract the data from the Content URI. Both on the new thread. I am putting all this data in 2 list views. Can I pass those list views using Handler and Bundle? which one is the good approach

Comment: You can use Handlers  if you want to do some changes from Threads that arent the main UI thread.  So declare for ex: private Handler h=new Handler();  and in your thread call it like this:  h.post(new Runnable() { public void run() {...update list views...}});   Or you can try AsyncTask also. But anyhow you cant change the UI from your own Thread withouth the use of Handlers,AsyncTask....

Comment: @JanBo Actually i did. What i did is declared the variable for the list and adapter as static in scope. Now I am able to update the list from manual thread to UI thread. is it good? I have updated my code and posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673553/listview-updates-only-when-activity-restarts-android

Comment: I dont see any Handlers in your code there? Also dont start your thread in onStart, start it in onCreate method after you set the adapter and everything else.  Also your Thread isnt stoped when you say albumThread = null; in onStop method.

Comment: @JanBo Hi I have started my thread only at OnCreate. But the above comment by Howard Pautz states that "Also onCreate is may not be the best place to start a thread" . So i changed it to OnStart. Actually OnCreate is started first.. thats the reason I started there. But as he said so i thought moving it in onStart will help me. Finally thread.stop() is deprecated. and eclipse suggested me to fix null.

Comment: I would suggest having a private boolean running=true; in your thread, and a method in your thread that says stopThread() {running=false;}. and then in your onPause() you should call myThread.stopThread(). And in your run() method you should periodically check if(!running) return; Also dont call super.run() there is no need for it.  But also leave myThread=null, this way you are sure if someone exited your Activity while your thread was running it will stop.